# Visual Studio with mySQL

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I am relatively new to programming and have been wanting to delve into the back-end development. I have started to try and learn mySQL. The main issue I am running into is the fact that mySQL doesn't seem to be updated for VS 2020? I am using the newest version and during the mySQL install it says it requires 2015/17 or 19 to be installed. The issue I have is I cannot find a 2019 version of vs on their website. The download link just automatically downloads the newest version. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do? I am completely lost at this point. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what version of MySQL are you using and version of VS ?

Comment: The latest versions of both. 8.0 for MySQL and 1.52 for VS

Comment: and what exactly is the issue? you cannot install the MySQL?

Comment: Yes, the issue is okay for now since my knowledge is very limited with MySQL. In the future I will try to figure out the issue more when my skills grow, for now I can simply just use the command line client. Basically in order to install MySQL into VS it says you need 2015,17 or 2019